# What is the source that singing and clapping sweetens judgment

Tags: sources-mekorot, song-poetry, hands-fingers

I heard a [song](https://youtu.be/h0kU8E_EyBw)

"על ידי ניגונים ומחיאת כף מתמתקין כל הדינים".
Seeming to mean:
through singing (or songs) and clapping hands all the (negative) judgments (made in Heaven) get sweetened (less harsh)

Is this a right translation?
What is the source of these words?
What is the source of the source...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says in [likutei moharan 10](https://www.sefaria.org/Likutei_Moharan.10.1),1 (English audio [1](https://www.breslovtorah.com/shiurim/rlm-lesson-06b2-torah-10-para-1-4-mid/), [2](https://www.breslovtorah.com/shiurim/rlm-lesson-07a-torah-10-para-4-mid-para-10-mid/), [3](https://www.breslovtorah.com/shiurim/rlm-lesson-07b1-torah-10-para-10/)):
When there is G-d forbid judgements on the Jewish people, then through dancing and clapping the judgements are sweetened. (My translation).
See the entire torah 10 for further elaboration.

Comment: So it is not nigunim but rikudim