# Rebbe Nachman - quote on the power of dancing and clapping

Tags: quotations, chassidic-rebbe, breslov

I seem to remember reading somewhere in Chayei Moharan where Rebbe Nachman of Breslov said:

> "Had I known the power of dancing and clapping, I would not have fasted so much in my youth."

Does anyone know where this quote is located, if it exists at all?

Comment: Sounds like he's advocating  what Rambam recommends, getting aerobic exercise every day before eating, instead of fasting. (Mishnah Torah, De'ot, Chap.4:2)

Comment: Sure the quote is about dance and clap, not prayer?

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83027/5120

Comment: He said it about Hidbodedut - personal prayer, like @Oliver said.

Comment: @Daniel So if he said it about Hisbodedus, then why don't you find the source and post it up here as an answer.